# Aligning SMS/Call Log Permissions with Declared Core Functionality in Backup and Restore app

Tags: android, google-play, backup, android-permissions, mobile-application

I am facing an issue with the Google Play policy regarding the declaration of core functionality for an Android app that involves SMS/Call Log permissions. The policy specifically mentions the need for permissions to access sensitive information to make sense to users and be necessary for critical current features.

**Here's a brief summary of the issue:**

Issue Overview:
After submitting my app for review, I received feedback stating that the declared core functionality, which involves backup and restore for users, does not match the in-app experience. The focus is on SMS/Call Log permissions and the policy related to accessing sensitive information.

**My Approach:**
I have implemented a backup and restore feature where users can locally save SMS/Call Log data. Permissions are requested incrementally, and I strive to follow best practices outlined in the policy.

**Questions:**

1. Are there specific considerations I might be overlooking regarding the declaration of core functionality and permissions handling in my Android app?
2. How can I better align my in-app experience with the declared use case of backup and restore for users?
3. Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Google Play policies, specifically related to SMS/Call Log permissions, and successfully resolved it?

I thoroughly checked my app's core functionality, which involves the backup and restore of SMS/Call Log data. To align with Google Play policies, I explicitly declared the usage of SMS/Call Log permissions in the privacy policy, ensuring transparency about the purpose and local storage nature of the backup data.

In the privacy policy, I clearly stated that the backup data is stored locally on the user's device and not on any external server. Users have full control over when they want to initiate the restore process, maintaining their privacy and control over sensitive information.

Despite these efforts, my app is still in a state of rejection. I expected that the proper declaration of permissions and adherence to privacy guidelines would satisfy the review process and lead to the app's publication on Google Play. However, the rejection status suggests that there might be additional considerations or steps that I need to address.